# A constant and divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1/3n$ , can we rewrite it as $1/3 \times \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1/n$ and then conclude it's divergent ? It's true for convergent sequences but what about divergent sequences ? Intuitively , it seems reasonable to me but I don't know how to prove it .

Comment: Yes you can. If the series diverges, it tends to $+\infty$, so $1/3$ of this sum diverges to $+\infty$ as well

Comment: Yes, it is true in the sense that if $c$ is a nonzero constant, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} ca_n$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. If they are convergent, their common value is $c\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$. If they are divergent, however, then the expression $c\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is meaningless.

Comment: @Atmos He/she wants to know whether this *is* really $1/3$ of this sum.

Comment: If you wish to, you can prove rigorously that $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum\alpha a_n$ for $\alpha\neq 0$ converges as well.  Use your definition of convergence and an epsilon delta arg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{3k}$, then $3u_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}\rightarrow\infty$, in other words, $3u_{n}\rightarrow\infty$. Now we prove that $u_{n}\rightarrow\infty$:

Given $M>0$, there exists some positive integer $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $3u_{n}>3M$, then $u_{n}>M$ for all such $n$, this proves that $u_{n}\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thanks but how we can prove it generally as @JMoravitz wrote ?

Comment: If $\displaystyle\sum a_{n}$ exists, say the limit is $L$, then $\displaystyle\sum\alpha a_{n}=\alpha L$ for $\alpha\ne 0$: Denote the partial sum of $\{a_{n}\}$ as $u_{n}$, given $\epsilon>0$, then $|u_{n}-L|<|\alpha|^{-1}\epsilon$ for large $n$, then $|\alpha u_{n}-\alpha L|=|\alpha||u_{n}-L|<\epsilon$, but $\alpha u_{n}$ is the partial sum of $\{\alpha a_{n}\}$.

Comment: Very nice , thanks a lot .